# Mutiple gesture recognizers on same UIImage

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to add 2 gestures to a uiimage that pulls a subVIew. One gesture is swipe to open/close. And the other is longpressand hold to open it at a specific height.

```
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1;
[imageNavigationSlider addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressWall = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                            initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(handleLongPressWall:)] autorelease];
longPressWall.minimumPressDuration = 1;
PullMeImage.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[PullMeImage addGestureRecognizer:longPressWall];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(swipe:)] autorelease];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft |     UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[PullMeImage addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
[swipe setDelegate:self];
```

The long press gesture is correctly recognized, but the swipe isn't.

I also tried using:

```
    -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
  return YES;
}
```

But with no success. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This should work. Can you please show us your swipe: method?